# RIDE-Selenium : Patch management with Firefox

Tags: firefox, selenium, selenium-webdriver, patch, robotframework

I have firefox 31 in my testing machine and I am using Robot framework to test functionality.
Before I was facing the problem like if I update firefox then my test case fails and then I did some research on it. Finally I found that there is lag between the time release of Firefox version and Selenium updates accordingly.

So now I am confused that to make our testing environment stable with new updates, how to proceed?
What could be the procedure for this Patch of firefox and Selenium library ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, updating FireFox causes an issue as sometimes there can be breaking changes, which are not addressed until a later date by Selenium?

If this is the case you have a few options which I imagine you're already aware of:

- Don't update until the Selenium update is released, until then, do not try and support something that could break.
- Update where you can, if a breaking change has been introduced, rollback and state you don't support that browser version.  With this method there's obviously potential for waste.
- Update and make changes to the tests in order to get them working for the latest version.  You can revert once the Selenium updates are out that address any breaking change.

Personally I would opt for the first option, given it is by far the simplest.  However, this may not be an option for you.

Comment: How would I get to know that Selenium new version release ?
Is there any possibility to get notification when Selenium releases new version with stable Firefox version via RSS or any kind of subscription ?

Comment: hey sorry I didn't notice this until now.  I regularly check https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/selenium-users for problems and I'm generally kept informed of upcoming releases via that.  I'm not sure of alternatives as I've never needed them